# Update(populate) SQL Table column with data from another database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases, `test1`and `test2`. `test1` has the following `table1`.

```
ID | Word      | Def
1.   abandon     NULL
2.   test        NULL
```

And for `test2` database, I have the following `table2`.

```
ID | Word      | Def
1.   abandon     (verb) the meaning of abandon
2.   word2       the meaning of word2
3.   abandon     (noun) the meaning of abandon
```

I want to copy the definitions of words from the database `test2`, `table2` to database `test1`, `table1` where a word from table1 matches with the same word from `table2` and avoid duplicate word; for example, the word `abandon` appears twice in `table2` and only once in `table1`. If possible, I want to append the second definition of the word `abandon` appended to the first definition and update it in `table1`, `Def` column.

I have tried the following.

```
UPDATE test1.table1 
SET Def = (SELECT Def 
           FROM test2.table2 
           WHERE test1.table1.Word = test2.table2.Word);
```

But I am getting an error which I do not quite understand.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get only one definition.  Here is an approach that works in MySQL and Postgres:

```
UPDATE test1.table1 t1
    SET Def = (SELECT Def
               FROM test2.table2 t2
               WHERE t1.Word = t2.Word
               ORDER BY id
               LIMIT 1);
```

The `LIMIT 1` might alternatively be `select top 1` or `fetch first 1 row only`.

Comment: Could you please explain what is happening inside the second query? Is it running like a while loop and update t1 until it does no longer find t1.Word = t2.Word? My sql knowledge is pretty limited.

Comment: It is a correlated subquery.  It generates all matching rows according to the `where` clause, then applies the `order by` and `limit` to get one of them.